# Command Line regedit key export syntax

Tags: windows-7, command-line, syntax

I'm attempting to export a specific key value in command line (Win7) and I don't think I have the syntax down correctly. I have found a number of examples that show the correct order, but I think the path I'm using is incorrect. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's what I tried:

```
regedit /e c:\users\<user>\Desktop\exportedkey.reg HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\FontAndColors\{A27B4E24-A735-4D1D-B8E7-9716E1E3D8E0}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: I'm not sure what part of the faq this is relevant to. ?

Comment: I apoligize for not being clear. Your question is great, but how does it relate to programming?

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I was calling the regedit command in a Process inside a C# app. It seemed a bit too wordy to include all that. I decided since I wasn't including any C# code to not mention it. In retrospect it does seem a bit unrelated. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to quote the path to the reg file, even if it doesn't contain spaces.

Comment: Thanks. I just realized that as you posted it. Facepalming ensued.